# The elements of a Random Forest Classifier in R

Tags: r, random-forest

What is the "elements" of a random forest classifier in R?
Why does the "elements" always equal 19 no matter what data set, what number of features I use? 
For example, in my R Studio Environment:

Name of the R object            Description
rf_goodjunk                            Large randomForest.formula (19 elements, 24.9 Mb)
rf_more                                  Large randomForest.formula (19 elements, 18.9 Mb)
rf_1                                          Large randomForest.formula (19 elements, 12.6 Mb)
rf_2                                          Large randomForest.formula (19 elements, 15.2 Mb)
rf_3                                          Large randomForest.formula (19 elements, 13.2 Mb)

Comment: which random forest function and from what package ?

Comment: The returned object of `randomForest::randomForest` is a list of 19 elements. It's the structure of the object. The content of course changes depending on the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random forest returns a list objet, containing several elements which always will be 19 if the function return 19 elements.

The number you refer to describes the number of elements inside a precise list, and is not due to Random Forest particularly, but is a standard behavior.

For example, `l <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)` returns a list of 12 elements : the coefficient, the residuals, etc...